# What is the difference between XYPixmap, ZPixmap, XImage, XShmImage and Bitmap in X?

Tags: bitmap, xlib, xorg

The only fact I know is that `XImage` is stored on the client side and the pixmaps are stored on the server side. Is it so simple?

Then what is `XY` and `Z Pixmaps` and why `X` needs so many types of image formats?

Why there is no `XY` and `Z Images`?

And what is Bitmap in the context of `Xlib` and why there is a function `XCreateBitmapFromData` that returns Pixmap handle? (or pointer? or structure?)

Answer (score 9):

From the X11 protocol specification:

> The data for a pixmap is said to be in XY format if it is organized as
>   a set of bitmaps representing individual bit planes, with the planes
>   appearing from most-significant to least-significant in bit order.

Which means for an RGB image you have all the red channel data followed by the green and then blue instead of the more traditional RGB triplets (ZPixmap).

Comment: Not very clear (as all X11 documentations) and in addition does not looks trustworthy. Maybe some detailed description will be better. For example, why the planes must contain R, G and B bytes? Maybe they are *bit* planes and the first plane contains only the first bit of every pixel, the second - second and so on?

Comment: Yeah, it's not majorly clear but I *think* that's a description of how you'd probably use an XY format pixmap in real life. The more practical answer is "this is not the image format you are looking for".