# Length error when calling xcb PutImage via Rust binding

Tags: rust, xcb

I am trying to put a simple test image to a pixmap (and then to a screen).  However, I always get a length error. From all the C examples I could find (not many, none for Rust), this should work. I assume that I am getting something wrong. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

```rust
const B: u8 = 0x00; // background
const C: u8 = 0xCC; // corner
const E: u8 = 0xEE; // edge
const F: u8 = 0xFF; // foreground
const CROSSIMG: [u8; 120] = [
    B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, // 0
    B, B, B, C, E, E, C, B, B, B, // 1
    B, B, B, E, F, F, E, B, B, B, // 2
    B, C, E, E, F, F, E, E, C, B, // 3
    B, E, F, F, F, F, F, F, E, B, // 4
    B, E, F, F, F, F, F, F, E, B, // 5
    B, C, E, E, F, F, E, E, C, B, // 6
    B, B, B, E, F, F, E, B, B, B, // 7
    B, B, B, E, F, F, E, B, B, B, // 8
    B, B, B, E, F, F, E, B, B, B, // 9
    B, B, B, C, E, E, C, B, B, B, // 10
    B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, // 11
];

let pix_id = conn.generate_id();
conn.check_request(conn.send_request_checked(&x::CreatePixmap {
    depth: 8,
    pid: pix_id,
    drawable: x::Drawable::Window(screen.root()),
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
}))?;

let context = conn.generate_id();
let cookie = conn.send_request_checked(&x::CreateGc {
    cid: context,
    drawable: xcb::x::Drawable::Pixmap(pix_id),
    value_list: &[],
});
conn.check_request(cookie)?;

println!("{:?}", context.resource_id());

let req = &x::PutImage {
    format: x::ImageFormat::XyPixmap,
    drawable: x::Drawable::Pixmap(pix_id),
    gc: context,
    width: 10,
    height: 12,
    dst_x: 0,
    dst_y: 0,
    left_pad: 0,
    depth: 8,
    data: &CROSSIMG,
};
println!("request: {:?}, length: {:?} ", req, 0);
let cookie = conn.send_request_checked(req);
conn.check_request(cookie)?;
```

The error returned looks like that:

```
Error: Protocol(X(Length(RequestError { response_type: 0, error_code: 16, sequence: 17, bad_value: 37748738, minor_opcode: 0, major_opcode: 72, pad: 1 }), Some("x::PutImage")))
```

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but your `height` and `width` are inconsistent `20, 20` vs `12, 10`.

Comment: That shoud not be a problem. To my understanding, PutImage puts an image into a possibly larger drawable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Padding

I *bet* that you would get similar output than me when running the following:

```
$ xdpyinfo | grep 'depth 8'
    depth 8, bits_per_pixel 8, scanline_pad 32
```

This means that for `depth 8`, every image line must be aligned to a multiple of four bytes. Thus, for a PutImage with width 10, you need 12 bytes per line and your total pixel data needs to be 12*12 bytes.

The actual length check in the X11 server likely is [this one:](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/blob/636c9aa359eab45102c12a9fccb8f60587c7d485/dix/dispatch.c#L2117-2119)

```c
    if ((bytes_to_int32(lengthProto * stuff->height) +
         bytes_to_int32(sizeof(xPutImageReq))) != client->req_len)
        return BadLength;
```

`lengthProto` comes (in your case, `XYPixmap`) from this code in the same function:

```c
        length = BitmapBytePad(stuff->width + stuff->leftPad);
        length *= stuff->depth;
```

Relevant part of the [protocol reference](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#id2625443):

> Each scanline is padded to a multiple of bits as given by bitmap-scanline-pad. The pad bits are of arbitrary value.

### Pixel format

You are specifying a pixel format of `x::ImageFormat::XyPixmap`, while you actually want `ZPixmap`.

`ZPixmap` is the "usual" format that you expect (in this case: One byte per pixel). T

From [the specification](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#id2625443):

> If a pixmap is represented in XY format, each plane is represented as a bitmap, and the planes appear from most significant to least significant in bit order with no padding between planes.

For more information about this, see [What is the difference between XYPixmap, ZPixmap, XImage, XShmImage and Bitmap in X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323960/what-is-the-difference-between-xypixmap-zpixmap-ximage-xshmimage-and-bitmap-i) . Best description for XY format from that (IMHO):

> The more practical answer is "this is not the image format you are looking for".

Comment: You are right regarding the output of xdpyinfo. However, changing the size of the test image to 12x12 does not resolve the error. Anyhow, the information is valuable as I misunderstood the use of padding.

Comment: Ah, you are also specifying a XY pixmap format. TL;DR: Always use ZPixmap. Anyway, I updated my answer to contain some information about that.

Comment: Thanks. Not using ZPixmap was the problem.  I read about these formats somewhere else in the spec and totally misunderstood them. The link you posted clarifies a lot for me.